# If $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$ then what is $\tan 3x$ equal to?

Tags: trigonometry

Would $\tan 3x$ be equal to $\sin 3x/\cos x$? Or perhaps $\sin 3x/\cos 3x$?

Regards, Tom

Comment: It is the latter one.

Comment: @ThomasWinkworth Yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If some function is written as $f(x)$, then the value of that function at $3x$, written as $f(3x)$, is obtained by replacing **every** appearance of $x$ with $3x$. To make it easier, perhaps write your function like

$$\tan(y) = \frac{\sin y}{\cos y}$$

Now, set $y=3x$, and you get:

$$\tan(3x) = \frac{\sin(3x)}{\cos(3x)}$$

Comment: I was writing an answer with the same idea.  This is better. +1

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(X) = \sin(X)/\cos(X)$ now let $X = 3x$ and we obtain $\tan(3x) = \sin(3x)/\cos(3x)$

Comment: When writing in LaTeX, it's better to write `$\tan$` (resulting in $\tan$ and not `$tan$` (resulting in $tan$). I edited your answer now, but in future, I advise you to use the versions with the backslashes.